# Why is the Markov chain repeating itself?

Tags: python, class

I am trying to simulate Markov chains using classes in Python. Here is my code:

```py
import random
...
class Chain:
  def __init__(self, probabilities, start):
    self.probs = probabilities
    self.start = start
    self.names = list(self.probs.keys())

  def __iter__(self):
    self.pos = self.start
    return self

  def __next__(self):
    self.random_num = random.randrange(100)

    prob_l = self.probs[self.pos]
    for ind, prob in enumerate(prob_l):
      self.prob_sum += prob
      if self.random_num < self.prob_sum:
        exclude_names = self.names[:ind] + self.names[ind + 1 :]
        self.prob_sum = 0
        self.pos = exclude_names[ind]
        return self.pos
    return self.pos


chain = Chain({"A": [50, 25], "B": [50, 25], "C": [50, 50]}, "A")
chain_iter = iter(chain)
for k in range(100):
    print(next(chain_iter))
```

It kind of works as expected, but it sometimes will repeat the letter C. Because of the two 50s in the dictionary, it should have a 50/50 chance of going to A or B. It should never repeat.

Comment: can you just call `print(chain.next())` on every iteration?

Comment: Can't reproduce your problem in a Python terminal session. Sounds like something weird repl.it is doing.

Comment: I tested your code in repl.it. It works correctly.

Comment: @Mike67 Look at the top.

Comment: Oh. It stopped printing objects, but there's a new problem.

Comment: "C" should NEVER loop back to itself. It must have a 50/50 chance of going to "A" or "B", but I see "C"s looping back to themselves. What's going on?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You where seeing repeated C's because the index of the current node was not being calculated correctly.

Here is the updated code with comments:

```
class Chain:
  def __init__(self, probabilities, start):  # only called once
    self.probs = probabilities
    self.start = start
    self.names = list(self.probs.keys())
    
  def __iter__(self):  # only called once
    return self
    
  def __next__(self):  # each iteration
    import random
    self.pos = self.start  # next step
    self.random_num = random.randrange(100) # choice percentile must be in here
    i = self.names.index(self.pos) # get index of this node in big list
    prob_l = self.probs[self.pos]  # get probs
    self.prob_sum = 0  # start prob scan
    for ind, prob in enumerate(prob_l): # probs of going to another node
      self.prob_sum += prob  # until 100%
      if self.random_num < self.prob_sum:  # passed percentile, go to another node
        exclude_names = self.names[:i] + self.names[i + 1:]  # big list without this node
        self.start = exclude_names[ind]  # for next iteration
        break   # found percentile in probs
    return self.pos # add current pos to chain
    
chain = Chain({"A": [50, 25], "B": [50, 25], "C": [50, 50]}, "A")
chain_iter = iter(chain)
for k in range(100):
   print(next(chain_iter), end=" ")
```

Output (wrapped)

```
A B A A B B C B A B A C A B C B A C B A B C B B C 
B A B C B A C A B A A B C B B A B B A B A C B C B 
B C A B A C A C B A C A B A B A C A B B C B A B A 
C A C A C B A A C B A A B B B A A A C A A B A B B
```

Comment: What did you edit? Could you show me? I would really appreciate it.

Comment: The key difference is `i = self.names.index(self.pos)`.  In the original code, `ind` was used to get the position of the current node which is not accurate. `i` is 0-2, `ind` is 0-1 so C is always included in `exclude_names`.

Comment: That makes sense.